# Get Youtube VideoID details in array

Tags: php, api, zend-framework, youtube, zend-gdata

I've been struggling with this for hours and i have no idea why is not working.
I need to get Details from a VideoID using YouTube API and Zend, so i created a function like this

```
function listYoutubeVideo($id) {
$videos = array();

try {   
    $yt = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube();


    $videoFeed = $yt->getVideoEntry($id);
    foreach ($videoFeed as $videoEntry) {
        $videoThumbnails = $videoEntry->getVideoThumbnails();
        $videos[] = array(
            'thumbnail' => $videoThumbnails[0]['url'],
            'title' => $videoEntry->getVideoTitle(),
            'description' => $videoEntry->getVideoDescription(),
            'tags' => implode(', ', $videoEntry->getVideoTags()),
            'url' => $videoEntry->getVideoWatchPageUrl(),
            'flash' => $videoEntry->getFlashPlayerUrl(),
            'dura' => $videoEntry->getVideoDuration(),
            'id' => $videoEntry->getVideoId()
        );
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
}

return $videos;
}
```

The reason im doing it with an array and a function is because i wanna cache the function.

I have no idea what is wrong with the code, i use exactly the same one just changing getVideoEntry for other types of feeds and it works.

Comment: You're silently ignoring any possible exception, from the looks of this code. Why? That would be the first place I'd start to look for possible clues.

Comment: Furthermore, have you set error_reporting to a decent level (E_ALL) and are you diplaying them (or logging them)?

Comment: error reporting is on and im actually not getting any errors, just empty arrays.

Comment: And what about the exception I mentioned? Do you get an exception if you re-throw $e in the catch block? Like so `[ ... ] } catch(Exception $e){ throw $e; }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I duplicated your code and ran it. Now getVideoEntry seems to be returning a single video's data, but for some reason you expect it to be a collection? Also if you cache, you might want to create some check for an empty data return.

Here is some revised code that worked perfectly for me:

```
function listYoutubeVideo($id) {
    $video = array();

    try {   
        $yt = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube();

        $videoEntry = $yt->getVideoEntry($id);

            $videoThumbnails = $videoEntry->getVideoThumbnails();
            $video = array(
                'thumbnail' => $videoThumbnails[0]['url'],
                'title' => $videoEntry->getVideoTitle(),
                'description' => $videoEntry->getVideoDescription(),
                'tags' => implode(', ', $videoEntry->getVideoTags()),
                'url' => $videoEntry->getVideoWatchPageUrl(),
                'flash' => $videoEntry->getFlashPlayerUrl(),
                'dura' => $videoEntry->getVideoDuration(),
                'id' => $videoEntry->getVideoId()
            );

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        /*
        echo $e->getMessage();
        exit();
        */
    }

    return $video;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is a bug in Zend framework:

http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-12461?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:all-tabpanel#issue-tabs

For a fast fix you can edit Zend/Gdata/YouTube/VideoEntry.php

line 587:

```
// $videoId = substr($fullId, $position + 1);
$url = $this->getFlashPlayerUrl();
$videoId = substr($url, 25, 11);
```

It's not fancy but gets the job done.