# Checking Validity of youtube video URL

Tags: php, zend-framework, youtube, zend-gdata, invalid-url

I am developing an application that takes input of youtube video link from user and embeds it on the page. Is there any mechanism through which I can check if it is a valid link.
Any method to check it either client side or server side will work.

**Note**- I am using **zend framework**

Comment: refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383073/how-do-i-check-if-a-video-exists-on-youtube-using-php

Comment: [stackoverflow.com/questions/4653894](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4653894/get-youtube-videoid-details-in-array) helped too, in case someone else wants to know.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I check if a video exists on YouTube, using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383073/how-do-i-check-if-a-video-exists-on-youtube-using-php)